# Filter a list based on a Hertz unit

Tags: c#

I need to filter a list based on hertz unit. I have the following scenario and my solution:

I have a list with objects. These objects contain a timestamp. I am sorting the list based on the timestamp. So with the first and last element of the list I can calculate the whole time captured by this list.

I have a samplingrate, which is e.g. 1,5 Hertz.

At the moment I am using this formular:

```
TotalTime * samplingrate = amountOfValuesToBeKept

(sizeOfList / amountOfValuesToBeKept) = xthElementINeedToTake
```

With this I assure to keep somehow a balanced amount values through the timespan of the list. Still, I am not sure if this is the best solution or if there are other/better ones.

I hope you understand my situation.

Best regards

Comment: As I read it, you try to downsample the input from whateeer Hertz you got to 1.5 Hertz?

Comment: It is really difficult  to help you without code, can you provide it and expected result?

Comment: "_Still, I am not sure if this is the best solution or if there are other/better ones._" Neither do we. We (kinda) know what you want to do, but we don't know _why_ you want to do that -- so who knows what other approaches are feasible and better...

Comment: It depends what you are trying to achieve. Is the sampling rate (1.5 Hz) important or is the resulting number of samples important? E.g. if you want to draw a curve it is probably not a good idea to have more samples than pixels. Why are you trying to reduce the number of samples? What is the maximum frequency of the signal? The sample rate needs to be at least 2 times the max. frequency of the signal (see [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)). Lots of questions...

Comment: @Christopher yes you are right :)

Comment: Actually the scenario is exactly like @Christopher said it. It is not just based on 1,5 Hertz, but the Hertz the user wants.